# Fixing "Cannot read property 'toStringTag' of undefined" in Webpack/Sass build

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, webpack, sass

I updated several NPM packages and now I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR in ./styles/main.scss
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toStringTag' of undefined
    at module.exports.module.exports (/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-1!/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js!/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/sass-resources-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--5-4!/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/src/styles/main.scss:121:63)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-1!/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js!/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/sass-resources-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--5-4!/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/src/styles/main.scss:735:21)
...
    at /mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-1!/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js!/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/sass-resources-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--5-4!/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/src/styles/main.scss:85:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-1!/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js!/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/sass-resources-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--5-4!/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/src/styles/main.scss:88:10)
    at Module._compile (/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at exec (/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js:60:10)
    at /mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js:153:14
    at /mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:343:11
    at /mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:681:15
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:24:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at /mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:678:31
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at /mnt/d/Dev/node/tools/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1423:35
```

I'm using Node 12, which supports Symbols. I tried deleting `node_modules` and re-installing.

How would I fix or debug this?

I searched the Mini CSS Extract Plugin and CSS Loader codebases and neither uses `toStringTag`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding `import 'core-js/modules/es.symbol';` since `babel/preset-env` wasn't including it.